# AttributeError: 'SeleniumClient' object has no attribute 'Edge_options' what is my mistake?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, twitter, screen-scraping, edgedriver

I'm new to using this platform, I'm sorry if the way I asked was wrong.
i want to get data from twitter(X) using selenium, but there is something wrong,and I don't understand.
i wanted to use edge driver because I had a google driver version error

the output I get when I run the code   **AttributeError: 'SeleniumClient' object has no attribute 'Edge_options'**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd

class SeleniumClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Initialization method. 
        self.Edge = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
        self.Edge_options('--headless')
        self.Edge_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.Edge_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')

        # you need to provide the path of chromdriver in your system
        self.browser = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Trinity\edgedriver\msedgedriver.exe', options=self.Edge_options)

        self.base_url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q='

    def get_tweets(self, query):
        ''' 
        Function to fetch tweets. 
        '''
        try: 
            self.browser.get(self.base_url+query)
            time.sleep(2)

            body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

            for _ in range(3000):
                body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
                time.sleep(0.3)

            timeline = self.browser.find_element_by_id('timeline')
            tweet_nodes = timeline.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tweet-text')

            return pd.DataFrame({'tweets': [tweet_node.text for tweet_node in tweet_nodes]})

        except: 
 
            print("Selenium - An error occured while fetching tweets.")




selenium_client = SeleniumClient()

tweets_df = selenium_client.get_tweets('AI and Deep learning'
```

when I ran the code, I thought I could get data from twitter(tweet scrapping)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium expects the options to be set the following way. This is only applicable for Selenium 4 upwards.

```
    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

For more details see: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/edge/